# no game sounds with XFCE and pulseaudio

Tags: debian, audio, xfce, pulseaudio, steam

Since recently I have sound problems ingame but now I have no ingame sounds can someone help me? Which info should I provide?
EDIT: For saved videos the same.

Comment: What game are you using?  What backend (alsa, oss)?

Comment: I use alsa but I have pulseaudio installed too.

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci`, `lsmod`?  What sound card are you using?  Have you unmuted the channel in alsamixer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that I can change the device of the audio-stream

Comment: a hint if you can't change the device output then go to 'Output Devices' and hen you remove the tick next to the devices that you don't need.